# joining two tables in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have problem with joining two tables and i am so confused, so i made new project as this example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association i have two tables customers and orders.

My models

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  attr_accessible :id, :name
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  attr_accessible :id, :count, :customer_id
end
```

In migration orders table, i have reference to customers table realized with:

```
t.references :customer
```

I fill tables with some sample data and run this sql query which is working.

```
select * from customers inner join orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id;
```

than i open rails console and run this query:

```
Customer.joins(:orders)
```

which give me result of only customers, but i hope for merge of two models and appropriate result. when i run

```
Order.joins(:customer)
```

it return me only result of orders.

Is there option for retrieve merge result of two models? Thanks in advice :)

Comment: so each customer record can have many orders. If you select a customer object by random and do : @customer.orders, you should see all the orders associated with that customer

Comment: for eg: c = Customer.first
orders = c.orders
Now orders will contain all the records associated with that customer

Answer (score 2):

To include related tables in a query, use :includes

```
Customer.includes(:orders)
```

To only utilize related tables in query conditions, use :joins

```
Customer.joins(:order).where(:unpaid => true)
```

But you have another issue, in that even when you use do 'Customer.includes(:orders)' in the console, it still will only show you Customers, because that is primary call. But, the data is available without additional calls to get the order information. Examine the logs on after a view has rendered using both 'includes' and 'joins' and you'll see the difference in the number of calls.

Assuming you make the different calls in your controller and put the following in your view.

```
<% @orders.each do |o| %>
  <%= customer.order.details %>
```

Comment: Many thanks to all response. I used also joins in controller, and read all stack errors in browser. There was two types of errors: problem with model and some bad class... iam new to rails, i'm java developer, and i have experience with hibernate and mybatis and i thing, error is near my bad asociation or something like this. Rails can find two tables and join them... now i see how to do. rails is so groovy :))

Answer (score 1):

To access customers' orders do :

```
customers = Customer.joins(:orders)
customers.each do |customer|
  customer.orders #<= contains orders for this customer
end
```

The other way around :

```
orders = Order.joins(:customer)
orders.each do |order|
  order.customer #<= contains the customer
end
```

Note that using `joins`, you're doing an inner join and therefore exclude customers without orders ... if you want to include them, use `includes(:orders)` instead